# LiveServerTestCase server sees different database to tests

Tags: python, mysql, django, testing

I have some code (a celery task) which makes a call via `urllib` to a Django view. The code for the task and the view are both part of the same Django project.

I'm testing the task, and need it to be able to contact the view and get data back from it during the test, so I'm using a `LiveServerTestCase`. In theory I set up the database in the `setUp` function of my test case (I add a list of `product` instances) and then call the task, it does some stuff, and then calls the Django view through `urllib` (hitting the dev server set up by the `LiveServerTestCase`), getting a JSON list of `product` instances back.

In practice, though, it looks like the `products` I add in `setUp` aren't visible to the view when it's called. It looks like the test case code is using one database (`test_<my_database_name>`) and the view running on the dev server is accessing another (the `urllib` call successfully contacts the view but can't find the product I've asked for).

Any ideas why this may be the case?

Might be relevant - we're testing on a MySQL db instead of the sqlite.

*Heading off two questions (but interested in comments if you think we're doing this wrong):*

- I know It seems weird that the task accesses the view using `urllib`. We do this because the task usually calls one of a series of third party APIs to get info about a product, and if it cannot access these, it accesses our own Django database of products. The code that makes the urllib call is generic code that is agnostic of which case we're dealing with.
- These are integration tests so we'd prefer actually make the `urllib` call rather than mock it out

Answer (score 0):

The celery workers are still feeding off of the dev database even if the test server brings up other databases because they were told to in the settings file.

One fix would be to make a separate settings_test.py file that specifies the test database name and bring up celery workers from the setup command using subprocess.checkoutput that consume from a special queue for testing. Then these celery workers would feed from the test database rather than the dev database.